«Ботинки размером на великана»
Вопрос о лексической сочетаемости: можно ли использовать это выражение (ботинки размером на великана) или лучше заменить на другое сочетание?

• Вот что имеется в словаре управления:
размер
1. размером в (при выражении в единицах измерения). Комната размером в двадцать квадратных метров.
2. размером с (при указании на предмет, к которому приравнивается по величине другой предмет). Мышь размером с крысу.
• Имеются правильные примеры:
ботинки размером — с маленькое ведёрко, с батон каждый, с небольшую подводную лодку, с приличный чемодан, в 1 метр, в палец;
сапоги размером — с небольшую лодку,  с доброе ведро каждый, с наперсток,  в три её ноги каждый, с человеческий дом.
• Имеются и единичные, особенные:
Да, мне уже показали и плащик, и сапоги размером на горного тролля (А. Одувалова. (Не)идеальная работа); В России пока не начали изготавливать туфли размером для йети (А. Саудер. Тень под лампой. Лу-Фадо).
✦ Я считаю, что лучше изменить выражение (изничтожить слово "размером"): ботинки на великана или ботинки для великана.
Перед великим революционным праздником наконец-то пришли специальной посылкой новые ботинки для большеразмерных бойцов (Виктор Астафьев. Прокляты и убиты).
